# Is there a way to add and run a amqp broker connection without rebooting the broker?

Tags: activemq-artemis

Or there is only one way - add the configuration to the broker.xml and restart the broker, only then the broker connection will work. I found in `embeddedActiveMQ.getBrokerConnections()`, can I do it somehow with this?

Artemis version 2.19.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code there doesn't appear there is any way to add an AMQP broker connection at runtime. At this point you'd have to modify the configuration (whether that's in-memory on or disk (i.e. `broker.xml`)) and restart the broker.

Support for this use-case could potentially be added in the future, but you would have to move beyond 2.19.x to get it which would also require Java 11.